# How to access ubuntu machine from another network

Tags: networking, server, remote-desktop, remote-access

I recently installed Mattermost chat software on ubuntu. This Machine is sitting in our office on our LAN, i can connect to the mattermost interface http:IPADDRESS:8056 from any PC in our MPLS network.

The problem here is we use citrix zendesktop for all our users - which is located on another network.

I found the public IP address of the Ubuntu machine (lets say 175.XXX.XXX.74). I can ping that IP address from inside our hosted desktops fine. However when I try to browse to that address in my browser I get

```
Gateway Timeout
Server error - server 175.184.197.74 is unreachable at this moment.
Please retry the request or contact your administrator.
```

Im relatively new to linux so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

### First solution

I consider 175.184.197.74 is the gateway of the local network of IPADDRESS:8056.

To establish a connection, 175.184.197.74 must forward traffic incoming by 175.184.197.74:8056 to IPADDRESS:8056.

Since I don't know what is 175.184.197.74, I can't help you more.

### Second solution

If you can't find how, you could use a reverse ssh tunnel to a remote host reachable by both.  There's a ton of very cheap VPS out there.

On ubuntu host you can do :

```
ssh -R 8056:localhost:8056 user@remoteIP
```

This will open a tunnel between remoteIP and IPADDRESS

This way, When you reach remoteIP on port 8056, traffic will be redirect to IPADDRESS on same port.

This access will be temporary. You should set the tunnel by using autossh in /etc/rc.local.

Good luck !